# Typescript: получение значения input

Tags: javascript, typescript

Есть два текстовых инпута:
(синтаксис jade)

```
input#x.game__input.game__input_text(type='text', value='X')
input#y.game__input.game__input_text(type='text', value='Y')
```

Есть js, получающий их значение:

```
let x = Math.floor(Math.abs(document.querySelector('#x').value));
let y = Math.floor(Math.abs(document.querySelector('#y').value));
```

Почему интерпретатор typescript ругается на значение value:

> error TS2339: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'Element'.

Спасибо!

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.querySelector` в `Typescript` возвращает объект с интерфейсом `Element`. В свою очередь этот интерфейс не имеет такого свойства как `value`. Чтобы избежать этого, нужно возвращаемое значение сперва привести к `HTMLInputElement`, у которого есть `value`.